# Error #1010 on a button

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have a button on frame 2.

```
stop();

easy_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onEasy);
function onEasy(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(4)
}
```

When I click on it, it gives this in the output:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at SpaceInvaders_fla::MainTimeline/frame4()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at SpaceInvaders_fla::MainTimeline/onEasy()
```

I don't understand why it is doing this.

Comment: Do you actually have a frame 4 on the main timeline??? Also why even have a frame 2? Just put all code on frame 1 and use `addChild` to show something (the MovieClips, Sprites or Buttons you have on frame 2 or frame 4) and `removeChild` when you want them gone...

Comment: Most likely something is null (undefined) in your code on frame 4, you should post that code here as well

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one frame on your main timeline.

Your button can have 4 frames, that's fine.

gotoAndStop(4) is telling the main timeline to go to frame 4 because that's where the code "lives".  It's "this" in the scope of the code that's executing.

you can do event.target.gotoAndStop or you can do button_name_here.gotoAndStop.